# How can I get local web pages to always open in a new window in XP?

Tags: html, url, windows-xp, local

I am running windows XP 2003 sp3. Ie is the default browser.  If I have a web page open and then open a local web page it will always open it in the existing window. I want local web pages and url shortcuts to always open in a new window. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Somehow I don't think you are asking for programming help but I'm going to respond appropriate to the forum. Use the target attribute on your links to force browser window/tab actions. Valid standard options are: `_self`, `_blank`, `_top`, `_parent`. Use `_blank` to force the link to open in a new tab/window as per the default behaviour you have setup in IE.

```
<a href="example.html" target="_blank">Example</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this can be done. The thing is windows XP will tend to open any local web page files and its shortcuts with the "Default Programs" that's mapped to that file type. So in your case, the IE being the default browser program, it opens in a new tab.
The same file will open up starting IE if there isn't any instance of IE already running. So I think the simple way to do your need is to have another IE instance running, and drag-drop the file you wan't to open into the IE window, which will open it.

P.S: other browsers like chrome allows dragging the tab outside the window to open up in a different window.